# I need help figuring out the meaning of "frost-worked"

Tags: meaning

I happened on the sentence below while browsing the internet, but I'm not sure what "frost-worked" means.

"Some brittle oak leaves still cling to their branches like tattered camouflage while tiny salt hay spindles scud across withered grass and frost-worked asphalt"

Comment: I've seen "frost work" used to describe the lace-like frost formation on a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Frost-worked* means some surface that has been affected by the freeze-thaw cycle.  To get an idea of the effect, read from *Pages of Stone* (2nd Edition) by L. and H. Chronic:

> As **frost worked** on rock already weakened by solution of its
>   calcium carbonate cementing material, thick slabs and sheets of rock,
>   and occasionally large blocks, fell away and deepened some of the
>   recesses until they were large enough to be used as living space...

"Frost-worked asphalt" would be at least cracked and possibly heaved.

Comment: It's only my opinion, but I think it's a purely visual image, invoking lacework (per @HotLicks ' comment), [fretwork](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fretwork&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=923&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI1vCVgfbQyAIVCtcaCh2zSAt6) etc. I didn't read it as structural damage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "frost-worked" is indicating something the frost has acted upon; something covered with frost.